# How to Create Nested Group By in UnderScore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array I need to group them based on size_y;

```
[
    {"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":4}, 
    {"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":2}, 
    {"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},
    {"col":1,"row":4,"size_x":3,"size_y":1}, 
    {"col":1,"row":5,"size_x":4,"size_y":1}
]
```

Now, if size_y is 4 I want to group all the rows less than or equal to 4.

```
[
    {"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":4}, 
    {"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":2}, 
    {"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},
    {"col":1,"row":4,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},
],
[
    {"col":1,"row":5,"size_x":4,"size_y":1}
]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to get top data structure, from the bottom one? And bottom one is nested array? Is underscore a must?

Comment: no, from top data structure I need to get the bottom one. Underscore is recommended but not necessary.

Comment: What is the data structure at the updated question based on? All of the objects in the array have a `"size_y"` property, which `"size_y"` value should be evaluated?

Comment: initially, the 1st item should be checked. next, if the "size_y" is more then one then that should create another array as shown in the example. in the second step if the "size_y" is 2 and "row" is 2 then the nested array should contain the elements of row 2,3 only

Comment: @SravanSriram _"initially, the 1st item should be checked."_ Ok. _"next if the "size_y" is more then one then that should create another array as shown in the example."_ The element adjacent to the fist element has a `"size_y"` value less than the first element, which is not reflected in the resulting data structure at the updated question, correct?.

Comment: It's `size_y` or `size_x` the filter?

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't get what you are asking. can you just clarify?

Comment: @robe007 "size_y" is the filter

Comment: @SravanSriram The updated question is different from the original question. The two objects at the updated question are not the same: the third element of second array has `"size_x"` set to `1` though the first array is `3`. What do you mean by _"next if the "size_y" is more then one then that should create another array as shown in the example."_? Why does the object having `"size_y"` set to `2` create begin a new array though elements having `"size_y"` set to `1` not begin a new array? The original question was clear. The current question and explanation of a specification is inconsistent.

Comment: @guest271314 I have changed the arrays for better understanding. I meant that the next item in the list. if it is greater then one array need to be created and in that array, if the case is  "size_y" is 2 and "row" is 2 then the nested array should contain the elements of row 2,3 only

Comment: The original question did not mention `"row"` as a variable to evaluate. The explanation of the updated question is not clear. Instead of changing the question and adding requirements consider the question and what the expected result is before asking the question. The updated question is now entirely different from the original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 now kindly check the question. i am confident that now the question will be clear to you.

Comment: @SravanSriram No, the edited question is still not clear from perspective here. What is clear is that the updated question is different from the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187801/discussion-between-sravan-sriram-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator function and `.splice()`

```js
let arr = [
    {"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":4}, 
    {"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":2}, 
    {"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},
    {"col":1,"row":4,"size_x":3,"size_y":1}, 
    {"col":1,"row":5,"size_x":4,"size_y":1}
];

function* divideBy(a) {
  const [copy, [{size_y}] = copy] = [[...a]];
  while (copy.length) yield copy.splice(0, size_y);
}

let res = [...divideBy(arr)];

console.log(res)
```

Comment: size_y this will not be always same.

Comment: @SravanSriram The generator function accepts `n` as second parameter, where `n` is a positive integer

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS you can simply do using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr = [{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":4},{"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":3,"size_y":1}, {"col":1,"row":4,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":5,"size_x":4,"size_y":1}]

let op = arr.reduce((out,inp)=>{
  if(inp.row > 4){
    if(out['>4']){
      out['>4'].push(inp)
    } else {
      out['>4'] = [inp]
    }
  }else{
    if(out['<4']){
      out['<4'].push(inp)
    } else {
      out['<4'] = [inp]
    }
  }
  return out
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Comment: size_y this will not be always same